# Get only ID value in Json/xml

Tags: java, json, lombok

I have two jpa entities:

```
@Entity
public class Contact {

@Id
private Long id;
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "APPLICATION")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Application {

@Id
@JsonProperty("APPLICATION_ID")
@XmlElement(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty("CONTACT_ID")
@XmlElement(name = "CONTACT_ID")
private Contact contact;
```

So in my controller i'am getting json or xml of an application like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<APPLICATION>
<APPLICATION_ID>6</APPLICATION_ID>
<CONTACT_ID>
    <id>1</id>
</CONTACT_ID>
</APPLICATION>
```

but i need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<APPLICATION>
<APPLICATION_ID>6</APPLICATION_ID>
<CONTACT_ID>1</CONTACT_ID>
</APPLICATION>
```

Or in json i have:

```
{
"APPLICATION_ID": 6,
"CONTACT_ID": {
    "id": 1
}
```

but need:

```
{
"APPLICATION_ID": 6,
"CONTACT_ID": 1,
}
```

How can i get only applicationID ? All getters,constructors and setters are added by lombok.

Comment: So i decided to use DTO pattern and the solution become very simple and correct.

Answer (score 0):

using lombok, that means you also have getters generated. Use the following to map contact json, if only the id is what you need:

`@Data
public class Contact {
    @JsonValue
    private Long id;
}`

This will make json use the id as the entire serialized value.
For xml mapping, i think you have to implement an `@XmlJavaAdapter`